# count distinct gmail addresses

Tags: python, python-3.8

need to count distinct gmail addresses provided by user as input, here are the conditions:

not case sensitive :

```
"a@gmail.com" == "A@GmaiL.com"
```

The ‘.’ character in the string in the local name is ignored :

```
"aa@gmail.com" == "a.a@gmail.com"
```

Gmail domain is same as googlemail

```
"aa@gmail.com" == "aa@googlemail.com"
```

my issue is with the very last one. How to implement the last condition in my code?

```
distinct_emails=[]
email = []
count=0
 for i in range(int(input())):
  item = input().lower().replace(".","")
  email.append(item)

 for i in email:
  if i not in distinct_emails:
    count = count + 1
    distinct_emails.append(i)
print(count)
```

Comment: Just replace `@googlemail.com` with `@gmail.com` before the final comparison.

Comment: Oneliner solution: `print(len({input().lower().replace(".","").replace("@google","@g") for _ in range(int(input()))}))`

Comment: @tripleee Won't work, as they removed `.` already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, where for gmail and googlemail addresses, you check for the swapped versions before appending it to the `distinct_emails` list.

```
distinct_emails=[]
email = []
count=0
 for i in range(int(input())):
  item = e.lower()
  # don't remove `.` after the `@`.
  parts = item.split("@")
  email.append(parts[0].replace(".", "") + "@" + parts[1])

for i in email:
  # consider googlemail and gmail to be equivalent
  if not any(e in distinct_emails for e in [i, i.replace('@googlemail.com', '@gmail.com'), i.replace('@gmail.com', '@googlemail.com')]):
    count = count + 1
    distinct_emails.append(i)
print(count)
```

Comment: it's not returning the right answer : a@gmail.com
a.a@gmail.com
aa@gmail.com
a.a@GMail.com
a.a.a@googlemail.com
the expected answer is 3 but getting 0

Comment: It's because you are removing all the dots from the emails, including after the `@`. So by the time we get to the for loop, the emails look like this: "aa@googlemailcom".

One solution is to modify the `in distinct_email` checks to use domains like "googlemailcom"—that is, without the dot. Even better would be to not replace `.`s after the @.

Comment: @moin1010, I've edited the code based on this idea. Try it again.